# Regex not working during execution of Dynamic GUID while testing a web application using Jmeter? Could anyone assist me on this pls

Tags: regex, jmeter, guid

[I have tested the regex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctsxR.png) and it capturing the GUID but while execution this is failing to pick up and my script in Jmeter is failing due to this.

I've attached the test plan and thread details to this. [Test PLan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEKoD.png)

Error Msg: [Fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8j5Zg.png)

Regex used `[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}` to identify the path *www.abc.com/BudgetCalculator/**f23789f8-c409-4ca2-87ec-dc0cc7bf2975***

Im logging in and try to navigate to a hyperlink budget cal, but its failing and it loads the same home page instead of navigating.

I've used the debug sampler and its pulling through as null value [Debug Sampler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvchD.png)

**UPDATE** This has been resolved now, I've used the css sector extractor to read the href(+GUID) value from the response of the previous request and used that as a variable for the next request.

[CSS Selector Extractor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAI6F.png) 
[HTPP Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxNTl.png)

Comment: Is your template `$0$`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Yes, template is $0$.

Comment: In the next HTTP request, I have added ${guid} in the path field. I was hoping the regex would pick the GUID.

Comment: Is the Reference name field in the regex extractor set to `guid`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, you can see the attached links for images of regex, test plan and error msg.

Comment: Why is the Match No. set to 0? Use `1`.

Comment: Show HTTP request. It should work

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Tried with all possible Match no, used 1 as well. No luck

Comment: @user7294900 Image of HTTP attached: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEKoD.png   I've given ${guid} in path

Comment: The previous HTTP you take the value from

Comment: @user7294900: https://i.stack.imgur.com/axZXZ.png

Comment: There isn't any value to extract

Comment: @user7294900 I used same thing while log in as well. What should be there ideally to extract the GUID?

Answer (score 0):

In "**Fields To Check**", you're extracting from URL.

But your URL is "**/MyAccounts**" so it cannot work.

So either you have used the wrong "**Fields To Check**" and it should be "**Body**".

Or it's not the correct response you're extracting from.
So first find the response where the GUID is located, use View Results Tree for that, and add your extractor there.

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved now, I've used CSS selector extractor now and I can see the GUID coming through in debug sampler.

Comment: Could you give more details so that it's helpful to others ? thanks

Comment: Updated details above. @UBIKLOADPACK